# How to effectively execute this cron job?

Tags: php, cron

I have a table with 200 rows. I'm running a cron job every 10 minutes to perform some kind of insert/update operation on the table. The operation needs to be performed only on 5 rows at a time every time the cron job runs. So in first 10 mins records 1-5 are updated, records 5-10 in the 20th minute and so on.

When the cron job runs for the 20th time, all the records in the table would have been updated exactly once. This is what is to be achieved at least. And the next cron job should repeat the process again.

**The problem:**
is that, every time a cron job runs, the insert/update operation should be performed on `N` rows (not just 5 rows). So, if `N` is 100, all records would've been updated by just 2 cron jobs. And the next cron job would repeat the process again.

Here's an example:

This is the table I currently have (200 records). Every time a cron job executes, it needs to pick `N` records (which I set as a variable in PHP) and update the `time_md5` field with the current time's MD5 value.

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+ 
|      id | time_md5                            | 
+---------+-------------------------------------+ 
|      10 | 971324428e62dd6832a2778582559977    |  
|      72 | 1bd58291594543a8cc239d99843a846c    |  
|       3 | 9300278bc5f114a290f6ed917ee93736    |  
|      40 | 915bf1c5a1f13404add6612ec452e644    |  
|     599 | 799671e31d5350ff405c8016a38c74eb    |  
|      56 | 56302bb119f1d03db3c9093caf98c735    |  
|     798 | 47889aa559636b5512436776afd6ba56    | 
|       8 | 85fdc72d3b51f0b8b356eceac710df14    |     
|      .. | .......                             |     
|      .. | .......                             |     
|      .. | .......                             |     
|      .. | .......                             |     
|     340 | 9217eab5adcc47b365b2e00bbdcc011a    |  <-- 200th record   
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

So, the first record(id 10) should not be updated more than once, till all 200 records are updated once - the process should start over once all the records are updated once.

I have some idea on how this could be achieved, but I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your update mechanism a PHP script executed by cron?

Comment: Yes, it's a PHP script + mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Red/Black system (like for cluster management).

Basically, all your rows start out as black. When you run your cron, it will mark the rows it updated as "Red". Once all the rows are red, you switch, and now start turning all the red rows to be black. You keep this alternation going, and it should allow you to effectively mark rows so that you do not update them twice. (You could store whatever color goal you want in a file or something so that it is shared between crons)

Comment: I sorta want to do this without any extra file because there could be potentially dozens of the same PHP script running - only the variable N will change in each cron job.

Comment: You want multiple scripts to be modifying the same data set concurrently?

Comment: No, each cron job will update records in a range. In my actual table, each cron will be dealing with records of any particular year. So there will be 5 crons which will deal with records for the year 2000, 01,02,03,04 and 05 respectively.

Comment: Ah, Well I guess you could possibly store the red/black marker in another table to avoid writing any files?

Comment: I've settled with some kind of red/black system.

Answer (score 0):

I would just run the PHP script every 10/5 minutes with cron, and then use PHP's time and date functions to perform the rest of the logic. If you cannot time it, you could store a position marking variable in a small file.